# how to count multiple columns using countifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am putting in a formula  to count the number of times a quote is required Indicated by the letter `Q` in a given column, when I put the formula in for one column I get the correct answer, but when I want to do it for multiple columns I get zero, can anyone help please?
the formula is

```
=COUNTIFS(D10:D29,"=Q",G10:G29,"=Q")
```

Comment: If there's a Q in D10 and G10 what result do you expect - 1 or 2?

Comment: i just what to count how many q i add in each column

Answer (score 6):

Try either

`=SUMPRODUCT((D10:D29="Q")+(G10:G29="Q"))`

or

`=SUMPRODUCT(((D10:D29="Q")+(G10:G29="Q")>0)+0)`

the former will count 2 if you have Qs in both D10 and G10 - the latter only counts each row once at most, even if there are two "Q"s

Comment: fantastic that has worked (1st one) and if i wanted to add more columns just add more brackets and '+'? thanks

Comment: @wineslurp consider accepting this as an answer if its helpful to you. This is how we say thank you on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Your example (the first one) worked as expected, thanks. I tried with countifs first, but without success. Answer should be accepted by @wineslurp.

Answer (score 2):

countifs criteria are connected by a logical AND. so that formula is saying it must find your string in column D AND in column G. Apparently there are 0 instances of that. if you want the total number of cells with it then make it one range.

If the must be non-contiguous, use multiple countif formulas and add them

[image]

as a note, here I would change my formula back to countif, instead of countifs for backwards compatibility since I don't use the extra criteria.

EDIT: my second example was incorrect (See comments) so I removed it

Comment: using =COUNTIFS(E1:F4:H1:H4,"a") is the same as =COUNTIFS(E1:H4,"a") - it will count "a"s in G1:G4 too - you can't use a non-contiguous range in COUNTIF/COUNTIFS - even if you use a named range

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what I've found is that there is a way better way instead of the sumproduct, which can result in a overly-long formula if you have 5 columns. Instead, I found that using the SUM+IF function as we use the SUMPRODUCT, will achieve the result faster and better.

=SUM(IF((E:I="ABC")*(B:B="DEF"); 1; 0))

This function returns the number of rows that contain both "ABC" and "DEF" in the defined columns.

Spread the word!

Comment: You can still do that with SUMPRODUCT, e.g. `SUMPRODUCT((E:I="ABC)*(B:B="DEF"))` - like your version it could count a single row more than once if "ABC" occurs twice or more in a row (with DEF too, obviously)

Comment: You are correct. 

However, my point was that when trying to Google a solution, I was not able to find a satisfactory answer. But I agree, the SUMPRODUCT works as well.