# Excel - SUMPRODUCT to count if sum of columns is >0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very similar problem to another question I found which was submitted a year ago:

[how to count multiple columns using countifs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617601/how-to-count-multiple-columns-using-countifs)

I have data over several columns as either "0" or "1", and what I would like to do is count how many of these rows of data have at least one "1" in them.

I could always create an extra column as a sum of all results for that row, but I was wondering if there was a way around it.

I have tried the SUMPRODUCT formulae as specified in the first answer for the question linked above which would be perfect if it worked, however I have found this only works if I use data stored as text eg. X and Y. When I switch my data back to "0"s and "1"s all the formula returns is 0.

I'm not sure where to go from here, whether I can still use SUMPRODUCT, or if I can find a way using SUMIFS, COUNTIFS, or logical operators somehow. Thanks in  advance for any help.

Comment: The `SumProduct` formula modified to suit your data would be `=SUMPRODUCT(((D10:D29=1)+(G10:G29=1)>0)+0)` ie no quotes around the `1`'s.  (From your description I suspect you put them in quotes)

Comment: @chris You're exactly right, I did keep them in  quotes. I've changed it and it works the way I wanted it to now. Thank you! I knew it would be something stupidly simple.

Comment: Glad it worked.  That actually makes this a duplicate, so I'll close it as such

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one step with a complicated array function.  The following gets the number of rows that are all zeros:

```
{sum((1 - B1:B10) * (1 - C1:C10) * . . . )}
```

You can subtract this from the total number to get the rows that have at least one 1.  Essentially:

```
(count(A1:A10) - sum((1 - B1:B10) * (1 - C1:C10) * . . . )}
```